# Инициализация n-мерного массива нулями

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Возможно, вопрос уже был, однако я усердно искал и не нашел.
Как инициализировать динамический n-мерный массив нулями при объявлении?
Допустим:

```
const double arr_size = 10;
double *parr_x1 = new double[arr_size]();
```

но, это инициализация 0 для одномерного массива.
А как инициализировать, например, нечто подобное:

```
const double arr_size = 10;
double **parr_x2 = new double* [arr_size];
for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    parr_x2[i] = new double [arr_size];
```

Я так полагаю, что добавление скобок в цикле не поможет?

Comment: В С++ есть только одномерные массивы. Если делаете массив с указателями, то можно инициализировать их `new double [arr_size]{}`, или можно сделать только один массив `new double [arr_size * arr_size]{};` и соответствующее индексирование.

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете добавить фигурные скобки в цикле? Как-то непривычно с одним массивом. Нет, вопрос, так сказать теоретический. По идее, мне ничего не стоит написать цикл и каждому элементу 0 присвоить.

Comment: Я предлагаю инициализировать сразу при создании массива(ов).

Comment: В чем проблема? Просто внутрениий `new` сделать `new double [arr_size]()` и все. Все как и раньше. Откуда вы взяли это ваше "Я так полагаю, что добавление скобок в цикле не поможет"? На каком основании?

Answer (score 3):

Поможет... так и инициализируйте:

```
const size_t arr_size = 10;
double **parr_x2 = new double* [arr_size];
for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
    parr_x2[i] = new double [arr_size]{};
```

Убедитесь, что [все занулено](https://ideone.com/IduFy0):

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < arr_size; ++j)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << parr_x2[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как память, выделенная под n-мерный массив, выделяется единым блоком памяти, можно воспользоваться функцией [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset), которая сбросить каждый байт памяти в 0

```
#include <cstring>

std::memset(parr_x2, 0, sizeof(double)*arr_size*arr_size);
```

Comment: `memset` доступен и без подключения `cstring`

Comment: Не для способа выделения памяти, описанного у ТС...

Comment: согласно документации, находиться в указанном заголовке. В VS2017 также без подключения хедера, функция недоступна.

Comment: @Harry, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Он выделяет память **не** единым куском.